# Asynchronous PostBack stops mouseover event

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, onmouseover

I am using mouseover event on page.

Now, on button click to view more data, I have used Asynchronous PostBack. But after clicking on it, It stops mouseover event. How to prevent this problem ???

Answer (score 0):

write your code on ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("body").mouseover(function(){
     //do anything on mouse over
   });
})
```